# R Merge datasets not working as expected (many-to-many)

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge two datasets that share some of the same variables to have one dataset with variables 'EF' and 'LF' appropriately assigned.  However, for one of the variables ('Item'), the two datasets different in degree of complexity. I have provided both datasets below (which themselves are both subsets of larger datasets).

It seems that the merge is happening correctly, but the output is not what I was expecting.  Specifically (as an example), for 'Meat' the level names that result for 'Item.x' do not match that for 'Item.y'. I would only keep one of the 'Item' columns after the merge is complete, but I wanted to check that the output for 'Item.y' is correct for the concept before ignoring (and deleting) 'Item.x'.

From previous assistance and searching, I have tried various versions of the following code to merge df1 and df2:

```
merge.df <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("Region", "Group"), all=T)
```

For example, changing the order of df1 and df2 in the command, or adding "Item" into the 'by' function provide output that is entirely incorrect.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

INPUT
df1

```
Region  Group   Item    Stage   LF
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11
Europe  Marine      FSC1    9.4
Europe  Marine      FSC2    0.5
Europe  Marine      FSC3    6
Europe  Marine      FSC4f   9
Europe  Marine      FSC4p   5
Europe  Marine      FSC5f   11
Europe  Marine      FSC5p   10
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC1    3.5
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC2    0.5
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC3    1.2
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC4    0.713333333
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC5    7
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC1    4
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC2    0
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC3    0.5
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC4    2
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC5    8
```

df2

```
Region  Sub-Region  Group   Item    EF
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Bananas 0.35
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Grapes  0.41
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Europe  Fruit.Veg   Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Europe  Meat    Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Europe  Meat    Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Europe  Meat    Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Europe  Meat    Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Europe  Meat    Poultry 3.712
Europe  Europe  Marine  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    3.83
```

OUTPUT
merge.df

```
Region  Group   Item.x  Stage   LF  Sub.Region  Item.y  EF
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC1    20  Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC2    5   Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC3    2   Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4f   5.8935  Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC4p   2   Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5f   19  Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Apples  0.227686081
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Bananas 0.35
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Citrus  0.344375
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Grapes  0.41
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Fruit.Other 2.029212613
Europe  Fruit.Veg       FSC5p   15  Europe  Vegetables  0.917924249
Europe  Marine      FSC1    9.4 Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC2    0.5 Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC3    6   Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC4f   9   Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC4p   5   Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC5f   11  Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Marine      FSC5p   10  Europe  Fish.Seafood    4.117510463
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3 Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3 Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3 Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3 Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC1    2.3 Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10  Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10  Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10  Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10  Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC1    10  Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10  Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10  Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10  Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10  Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC1    10  Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5 Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5 Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5 Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5 Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC1    2.5 Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC1    7   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Bovine  FSC2    0.613   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Mutton  FSC2    0.618   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Goat    FSC2    0.618   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23    Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23    Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23    Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23    Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Pig FSC2    0.23    Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat    Poultry FSC2    1.765   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5   Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5   Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5   Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5   Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat        FSC3    5   Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333 Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333 Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333 Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333 Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat        FSC4    4.033333333 Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11  Europe  Bovine  22.68119086
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11  Europe  Mutton  20.99167461
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11  Europe  Goat    18.19083333
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11  Europe  Pig 5.04123312
Europe  Meat        FSC5    11  Europe  Poultry 3.712
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC1    3.5 Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC1    3.5 Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC2    0.5 Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC2    0.5 Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC3    1.2 Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC3    1.2 Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC4    0.713333333 Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC4    0.713333333 Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC5    7   Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Milk    FSC5    7   Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC1    4   Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC1    4   Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC2    0   Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC2    0   Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC3    0.5 Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC3    0.5 Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC4    2   Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC4    2   Europe  Eggs    3.83
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC5    8   Europe  Milk    1.308859756
Europe  Milk.Eggs   Eggs    FSC5    8   Europe  Eggs    3.83
```

Comment: When you are saying "factor", do you mean "factor" in the R sense, or do you actually just mean variable or value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're merging on just region and group, you are doing a many-to-many merge. So for example, for Europe and Fruit.Veg, you have 7 records in the first df and 6 in the second, so you end up with 42 (7*6) records in your merged table - this is the correct behavior for a many-to-many merge.

It seems like what you want is to include Item in the by statement of the merge, however it may not be giving you the behavior you expect because Item is missing in some of your df1 records. If that is not the case, could you explain what the incorrect behavior is when you add Item into the merge statement.

Comment: The "incorrect behaviour" is exemplified in the 'df.merge' output for 'meat' where 'item.x' may be different from 'item.y'. I was expecting them to line up. Including 'item' in the 'by' call doesn't produce the desired result. I'm happy to just eliminate 'item.x' column, but am trying to understand why the function call is behaving this way. And I am probably using the wrong syntax - by factor I guess I really mean variable. Thanks!